# Limiting scope of a variable to block in javascript (without using let)

Tags: javascript

Before let and es6, how could one do block-scoping in javascript? I have a function I need to make backward compatible but am running into lots of finicky issues:

Basically it is

```
for(let command in commands){
    // do something with the command 
}
```

and I would like to mimic the functionality without let. I realize it's a bit foolish going backward in time but I think this is the path of least resistance.

Comment: IIFE, or rename the variable, or use Babel.

Comment: @gcampbell thank you! Where would I rename the variable such that it was limited to the block? Within the for loop?

Comment: Maybe `for (var command$1 in commands) {}`. Then any other variables called `command` won't clash with it. The easiest option is to use Babel, which does this sort of thing automatically.

Answer (score 0):

The usual way is:

```
(function() {
    for(var command in commands){
        // do something with the command 
    }
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript pre ES6 doesn't have any notion of block scope. I'm afraid it isn't possible. Even if you were to use an IIFE, the variable would still be accessible outside the block, albeit just within the IIFE.

That's just how it works